# Convert a GroupBy object with no aggregation function into a dataframe while keeping the grouping

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have the following dataframe `df`

```
gender | country | age
-------+---------+-----
M         DK       20
M         ES       19
M         ES       21
M         DK       30
F         DK       20
F         ES       19
F         ES       21
F         DK       12
```

Is there a way to get the Grouped data as a dataframe e.g

```py
import pandas as pd
df_grp = df.group_by(["gender","country"])["age"] #Group it
df_grouped_df = pd.DataFrame(df_grp) #Convert to ordinary dataframe

print(df_grouped_df)

                   age
gender  country
------+----------+
                   20
 M      DK         30
        -------------
        ES         19
                   21

---------------------
         DK        20
F                  30
         ------------
         ES        19
                   21
```

EDIT:

Using `set_index` does not seem to work, since it does not group the second columns specified (e.g `country`);

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"gender":["M"]*4+["F"]*4,"country":["DK","ES","ES","DK"]*2,"age":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]})

 gender country age
    M   DK  1
    M   ES  2
    M   ES  3
    M   DK  4
    F   DK  5
    F   ES  6
    F   ES  7
    F   DK  8

df.set_index(["gender","country"])


                     age
   gender   country 
       M      DK        1
              ES        2
              ES        3
              DK        4
       F      DK        5
              ES        6
              ES        7
              DK        8
```

As noted it is not grouped for each `country` as required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not clean but has the visual aspect:

```
out = df.sort_values(['gender', 'country'], ascending=[False, True]).reset_index(drop=True)
out.loc[out.duplicated(['gender', 'country']), 'country'] = ''
out.loc[out.duplicated('gender'), 'gender'] = ''
print(out.set_index(['gender', 'country'])

# Output:
                age
gender country     
M      DK        20
                 30
       ES        19
                 21
F      DK        20
                 12
       ES        19
                 21
```

Answer (score 1):

First `groupby` in pandas is like iterator, so is necessary specify aggregate function(s) after it.

```
df1 = df.groupby(["gender","country"])["age"].sum().to_frame()
```

---

If need `MultiIndex`:

```
df1 = df.set_index(["gender","country"]).sort_index()
```

EDIT: You can check [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/advanced.html#creating-a-multiindex-hierarchical-index-object):

> We’ve “sparsified” the higher levels of the indexes to make the console output a bit easier on the eyes. Note that how the index is displayed can be controlled using the multi_sparse option in pandas.set_options():

```
df1 = df.set_index(["gender","country"]).sort_index()

print (df1)
                age
gender country     
F      DK         5
       DK         8
       ES         6
       ES         7
M      DK         1
       DK         4
       ES         2
       ES         3
```

---

```
with pd.option_context("display.multi_sparse", False):
    print (df1)
                age
gender country     
F      DK         5
F      DK         8
F      ES         6
F      ES         7
M      DK         1
M      DK         4
M      ES         2
M      ES         3
```

Comment: The issues with `set_index` is that is does not group the second group (I should've mentioned that I tried that). It has been added to the question

Comment: Use `.sort_index()` or `sort_values()` to reorganize your dataframe after `set_index`

Comment: it just sorts it - it does not make it a group

Comment: @CutePoison - hmmm, it is only displaying.

Comment: That is correct - I would like to check, if my grouping is correct, thus I wanted to inspect the grouped dataframe

Comment: @CutePoison - pandas dont display repeated values only, but in real there is no change

Comment: In this case, you need a third level...

Comment: It's odd that it does display the `M` and `F` as one group, but no the `country`

Comment: @CutePoison - it only display outer levels, all without last.

Comment: Roger that - thanks

Comment: @CutePoison - add link to docs.